# JavaScript - Adding an Image : React Native XCode

Tags: javascript, css, xcode, react-native

I am wondering how I would go about inserting an image into this??

I am also wondering whether this is javascript implemented on css or css implemented in javascript?

It was automatically generated by React Native as a default app starter pack and we are just getting to grips with the basics...

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';


class VLDB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style = {styles.welcome}>
      VLDB SQL Cheat Sheet!
      </Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to the SQL Cheat Sheet!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('VLDB', () => VLDB);
```

Cheers, Luke.

Answer (score 1):

To add an image to this, you first need to import in the image component

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
```

Then you add the image as described in [the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#content) by either referencing a locally bundled image or a remote image like so...

```
class VLDB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Image
            style={styles.icon}
            source={require('./myIcon.png')}
          />
         <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
          />
      <Text style = {styles.welcome}>
      VLDB SQL Cheat Sheet!
      </Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to the SQL Cheat Sheet!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How am I able to post the code back to you, I am using the first method,  require('./button.png')}

Comment: Here is the error: I receive:

Unable to resolve module .button.png from /Users/lcharlton/VLDB/index.ios.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/lcharlton/VLDB/button.png and its parent directories

Comment: So the "./button.png" path means that the button.png file exists in the same directory as the file which calls it (index.ios.js in your case). Is that where it is?

Comment: yeah and no the button.png is on my desktop and the index.ios.js is in another directory within my users documents.